# Are external config sections in web.config cached?

Tags: c#, asp.net, wcf, iis, web-config

I have my own custom configuration section, like this

```
<configSections>
   <section name="ConnectionStrings"
            type="System.Configuration.AppSettingsSection, System.Configuration, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a"
            restartOnExternalChanges="false"
            requirePermission="false" />
</configSections>
```

and I keep it in an external file like this

```
<ConnectionStrings configSource="connections.config"/>
```

I know that web.config is cached, and when I change the config, IIS resets the cache and reread the config again after restart...

But In my case, when I change my external config `connections.config` IIS doesn't restart the app because I set `restartOnExternalChanges="false"`.

Question: Is my external config cached as well? or IIS reads from it all the time when I use `ConfigurationManager.GetSection("ConnectionStrings")`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure, it is cached as well. The API `ConfigurationManager.GetSection` provides read-only view of the underlying configuration settings.